# hybrid and satellite views not working in android google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using the google maps api v2 in an android application and I am trying to use different map types. I am using the following code to change the type.

```
mMap.setMapType(2);
```

which should change the map to the satellite view, but when I call this the map shows up only as the gray grid of squares. I am testing this directly in google's example code for the maps API so I believe my initial set up is correct.

Is there something else that needs to be done to get different map views to work?

Comment: I would recommend using `GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE` instead of `2`. You might also try [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/NooYawk) (with a suitable change of API key to your own), as I can confirm that hybrid and satellite map types are working fine with it. In general, `setMapType()` is all you need, and if the regular tiles are coming up, my guess is that the problem is more tied to communications between your device and the Maps server.

Comment: could there be something wrong with my API code that it will connect to the server to get a normal map but not other map types?

Comment: Not that I can think of. My guess is that my app would exhibit the same behavior as yours, meaning that the problem is environmental, not programmatic.

Answer (score 3):

you can change the mapview type with these types of code

```
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything. those values are just constants, using an int of the appropriate value has the same result so 2 would be equivalent to using GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

Comment: well hybrid is 4 (but other than that you're right)